# problem adding an image as texture to an object

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to display an image in the gazebo environment. Looking at a few answers suggested that I've to add an object & lay the image as texture over the object.

I followed what's suggested in the answers of [this](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/4761/how-to-build-a-world-with-real-image-as-ground-plane/) post, but no avail. Then I created a collada mesh as suggested by [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=color_model#ExampleAddingColorandTexturestoaModel) tutorial. Still no luck. The object gets inserted like a grey plane as shown below.
[image: image description]

**What I did until now:**

1. I created a directory for the model with the name `~/.gazebo/models/aruco_marker`. This is how the folder looks like:

[image: image description]

2. contents of `model.sdf`:

   true

   ```
    <link name="link">
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <plane>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>10 10</size>
          </plane>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>100</mu>
              <mu2>50</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
        </surface>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
        <geometry>
          <plane>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>10 10</size>    </plane>    <mesh>
        <uri>model://aruco_marker/materials/textures/4x4_1000-25_side50.dae</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <script>
            <uri>model://aruco_marker/materials/scripts/aruco_marker.material</uri>
            <name>MyGroundPlane/Image</name>
          </script>
        </material>
      </visual>
    </link>   </model> </sdf>
   ```
3. contents of `model.config`

   Aruco Marker
        1.0
        model.sdf
        
            My textured ground plane.
4. contents of `materials/scripts/aruco_marker.material`

   material ArucoMarker/Image
   {
   technique
   {
   pass
   {
   ambient 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.0
   diffuse 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
   specular 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.5
   texture_unit
   {
   texture 4x4_1000-25_side50.jpg
   filtering trilinear
   }
   }
   }
   }
5. This is the .jpg file:
   [image: image description]

I generated a .dae file for it using [an online converter](https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/jpg-to-dae)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27834/problem-adding-an-image-as-texture-to-an-object/) by [user1928](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74396/user1928/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need to give the `<uri>` to the `materials/scripts` and `materials/textures` directory of your model, so that the material with the given `<name>` is read and the texture file is found.
i.e.

```
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>model://aruco_marker/materials/scripts/</uri>
        <uri>model://aruco_marker/materials/textures/</uri>
        <name>ArucoMarker/Image</name>
      </script>
    </material>
```

See this model from gazebo as an example http://models.gazebosim.org/pine_tree/

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/39778/veerachart/) with karma: 226 on 2022-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user1928](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74396/user1928/) on 2022-02-21**:
Thanks, it was helpful. I had another bug in my code. As can be seen in my post above, the name tag within the material tag in the visual section of my model.sdf file wasn't matching with the name mentioned in my .material script.

**Comment by [user1928](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74396/user1928/) on 2022-02-21**:
I tried generating the collada (.dae) file with blender but that wasn't required. The one generated with the online convertor (mentioned in my post) was good enough.